# android relative layout below above not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have one View in center position in my xml file,i added  two layouts firstabove my view and second bellow in my view.i have problem:
in android studio's design look perfect but when i run my app in ganymotion or device i have only second layout in full screen
this is a my source

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/choosetransactionuserimg"
>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"

    android:id="@+id/centerview"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:background="#D9c42251"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerview"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerview">
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is a android studio's verison]
i have no idea what is a wrong
if anyone knows solution please help me thanks

Comment: how  your layout is suppose to be? put screenshots

Comment: @ Rustam i updated it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/choosetransactionuserimg"
>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"

    android:id="@+id/centerview"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:background="#D9c42251"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerview"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerview">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i changed it but not working. second layout is always full screen.first not showing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use here Linear Layout as a main layout. by using this you ll manage your screen very easy. i am using this patent while i need your required type design.

- set Linear Layout which has `android:weightSum="3"`
- in first part add your first view, in second your middle view and in last and third add your bottom/last/third view
- give this three part Layout-wight as you need like 1st=0.25 2nd=1 3rd=0.25

Here is the example of it:

1. http://www.7solutions.in/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html
2. http://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-2/
   http://www.7solutions.in/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html

Comment: thanks but i want always one view in centr position and another above bellow.what is a wrong can you tell me in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

check it :

[image]

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/choosetransactionuserimg"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
              android:background="#D9c42251"

        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"

        android:id="@+id/centerview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerview"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you test this code ? i changed it but  nothink changed again @Rustam

Comment: @ Rustam i have same problem